# SQL - Order by column with specific value in front

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have the following query.

```
SELECT 
    A.*, B.QuantityOnHand, C.Brand, C.Category, C.Subcategory
FROM 
    item_info A
JOIN 
    inventory_status B ON A.ListID = B.ListID
LEFT JOIN 
    item_group C ON A.Parent_ListID = C.ListID
WHERE 
    (Conditions)
ORDER BY 
    Brand, Category, Subcategory, Name ASC
```

Let's assume I have brands A, B, G, X, and Z. I want to order the results so that brand X is first, followed by the other brands in ascending order. I also want to retain the ordering caused by the other columns, those being category, subcategory, and name.

The finished result would be something like this.

```
X
A
B
G
Z
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option

```
ORDER BY NullIf(Brand,'X'), Category, Subcategory, Name ASC
```

Brand X will be first, then it would preserve the remaining order of Brand

Comment: @user3308219 Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have to manually add them with a case statement.

```
ORDER BY 
     CASE Day 
     WHEN 'X' THEN 1
     ELSE 2
     END
```

Answer (score 0):

your could use  ORDER BY FIELD( column_name, values,..... )

```
  SELECT 
    A.*
    , B.QuantityOnHand
    , C.Brand
    , C.Category
    , C.Subcategory
  FROM item_info A
  INNER JOIN inventory_status B ON A.ListID = B.ListID
  LEFT JOIN item_group C ON A.Parent_ListID = C.ListID
  WHERE (Conditions)
  ORDER BY field(Brand, 'X', 'A','B','G','Z') , Category, Subcategory, Name ASC
```